# Undefined Index - isset guard doesn't work with helper

Tags: php, laravel, controller, helper, undefined-index

I have a multi-dimensional array coming from post request. It looks like this: `$request['bags'][1]['fruits']`. Sometimes, this value doesn't exist so it returns Undefined Index error.

```
$model->fruits = $request['bags'][1]['fruits'];
```

If I use an isset guard in my controller, **it works**:

```
$model->fruits = isset($request['bags'][1]['fruits'];) ? $request['bags'][1]['fruits'] : '';
$model->save();
```

Now, I wanted to wrap this in a function, so that I can use something like `nullable($fruits)` to make this work.

---

Now, I tried to wrap this inside a helper method; so I created Helper.php and added this method inside:

```
function nullable($value) {
    return (isset($value)) ? $value : '';
}
```

But in my controller, when I call `nullable()`, it throws Undefined Index error.

```
nullable($request['bags'][1]['fruits']); // Undefined Index

isset($request['bags'][1]['fruits']) ? $request['bags'][1]['fruits'] : ''; // works
```

Comment: If you use the `Request` object you can do `$request->input('bags.1.fruits', '')` which takes care of existence checks for you and returns a default (here `''`) if it doesn't exist. I think in laravel versions prior to 5.4 this was `$request->get` but not sure. Also laravel has `array_get` that works with the dot notation on arrays as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you encounter is, that the *Undefined Index Notice* is thrown as soon as the undefined index is requested. This happens as soon as you want to access the value behind the key upon calling your helper function with `nullable($request['bags'][1]['fruits'])`. The value is *extracted* and then send to the function.

What you can do instead, is using the [null coalesce operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php) `??` in PHP.

```
$model->fruits = $request['bags'][1]['fruits'] ?? '';
```

---

If you really want to create your own helper function though, you need to do it in a way, in wich the field is not accessed when the parameters are transfered to the function.

This can be accomplished by spearating the array from the keys you want to access.

```
function nullable(array $array, ...$keys) {
    $current = $array;
    foreach($keys as $key) {
        if (!isset($current[$key])) {
            return NULL;
        }
        $current = $current[$key];
    }
    return $current;
}
```

A call would then be `nullable($request, 'bags', 1, 'fruits');`

[Code example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ef28842d6190dc776363346583f58c6f6ba97799)

Comment: @NigelRen  agreed with you

Comment: @NigelRen Thanks for the hint :-)  Current [laravel requirements](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation) are 7.1.3 as an additional information.

Comment: @NigelRen What do you mean? It worked for me on php 7.2

Comment: It's surprising how many people are running php 5.x code, I just wanted to make sure that someone didn't try it and find that it was not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `condition? true : false :`

Means :

`$model->fruits = $request['bags'][1]['fruits'] ? $request['bags'][1]['fruits'] : '';`

OR :

`$model->fruits = $request['bags'][1]['fruits'] ?? '';`

Comment: The `?:` operator will still throw the notice